# looking for an alternative to refile in orgmode for emacs

Tags: vim, emacs, text-editors, text-editing, sublime-text-2

In emacs/orgmode there is something called refile.
you select text, hit refile and you get a list of your outline headlines, select one and your text goes there.

Can I achieve something like this in vim, sublime text or any other?

Answer (score 1):

VimOrganizer comes to rescue:
https://github.com/hsitz/VimOrganizer/blob/master/intro.txt

If the file above is accurate, it does support refiling -- but for .org files.